# VBA Copying Data from one worksheet to another but keeping data in one column intact

Tags: vba, excel

I need a solution to copy the data from one worksheet to another worksheet. Lets say from worksheet A to worksheet B. While copying the data the following condition has to be meet:
In worksheet B there is a column called "Comment". This Comment column should  remain intact or remain the same aligning to the data even if new data is copied or while copying any data has got deleted from the worksheet A.

So basically the comments should remain even thought we copy data from worksheet A to worksheet B.

I am not into VBA and looking for an example or solution

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I'm not into buying cars but I need a new car. The following condition needs to be met: it has to be a new Ferrari. Go buy me one.

Comment: current I am looping through both the worksheets, and check on a unique id column and when ever a new data is inserted or deleted than I am thinking to add a logic that the corresponding colmun(comment column) is not moved or deleted